# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not Tag. One of my loops isn't working

Tags: python, csv, beautifulsoup

The ultimate goal of this is to output select data columns to a .csv. I had it working once to where it only got the first table on the page but I needed both. Now it says this. Im quite new to python and IDK how I got to this point in the first place. I needed the call and put table but on the web page the calls came first and when I did .find I only got the calls. I am working on this with a friend and he put in the last two functions. He could get the columns I wanted but now we only get the calls. I tried to fix it and now it say the error in the title.

```
import bs4
import requests
import pandas as pd
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#sets desired ticker. in the future you could make this long
def ticker():
    ticker = ['GME','NYMT']
    return ticker

#creates list of urls for scrapet to grab
def ticker_site():
    ticker_site = ['https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/'+x+'/options?p='+x for x in ticker()]
    return ticker_site
optionRows = []
for i in range(len(ticker_site())):
    optionRows.append([])
    def ticker_gets():
        option_page = ticker_site()
        requested_page = requests.get(option_page[i])
        ticker_soup = BeautifulSoup(requested_page.text,'html.parser')
        return ticker_soup

    def soup_search():
        table = ticker_gets()
        both_tables = table.find_all('table')
        call_table = both_tables[0]
        put_table= both_tables[1]
        call_rows = call_table.find('tr')
        put_rows = put_table.find('tr')
#makes the call table
        for call in call_rows:
            whole_call_table = call.find_all('td')
            call_row = [y.text for y in whole_call_table]
            optionRows[call].append(call_row)

#makes the put table
        for put in put_rows:
            whole_put_table = put.find_all('td')
            put_row = [z.text for z in whole_put_table]
            optionRows[put].append(put_row)

        for i in range(len(optionRows)):
            optionRows[i] = optionRows[i][1:len(optionRows[i])]
        return optionRows

def getColumns(columnIndexes=[2, 4, 5]):
    newList = []
    for tickerIndex in range(len(soup_search())):
        newList.append([])
        indexCount = 0
        for j in soup_search()[tickerIndex]:
            newList[tickerIndex].append([])
            for i in columnIndexes:
                newList[tickerIndex][indexCount].append(j[i])
            indexCount += 1
    return newList


def csvOutputer():
    rows = getColumns()
    fields = ["Ticker", "Strike", "Bid", "Ask"]
    with open('newcsv', 'w') as f:
        write = csv.writer(f)

        write.writerow(fields)
        for i in range(len(ticker())):
            for j in rows[i]:
                j.insert(0, ticker()[i])
                write.writerow(j)


csvOutputer()
```

Comment: It would help if you could [edit] your question to explain what you are trying to actual do (not what the script is doing). i.e. extract what info?  Also show what your desired output would be for that site.

Comment: I would suggest you add print statements so you can see what is happening, i.e. print the contents of your variables to verify they are what you thought they should be.